# Compound commands in && / || condition

Tags: bash, shell-script

I know this is a common question and I have even seen answers to it before, but I cannot remember what they were nor find them.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -m         # allow for job control
EXIT_CODE=0    # exit code of overall script

function foo() {     
     for job in `jobs -p`; do
         echo "PID => ${job}"
         wait ${job} ||  { echo "At least one test failed with exit code => $?" ; EXIT_CODE=1; }
     done
}

trap 'foo' CHLD
```

My question concerns this line:

```
wait ${job} ||  { echo "At least one test failed with exit code => $?" ; EXIT_CODE=1; }
```

If `wait ${job}` yields a non-zero exit code I'd like to echo out the statement and then do an assignment (assigning 1 to `EXIT_CODE`).

I don't believe my syntax is correct. I am not getting any obvious errors, but I am pretty certain it's not correct because the statement is not being echoed. But I am still exiting with an exit code of 1.

Comment: That `wait...` line already looks good to me. I assume you've not provided your entire script, though, so there's only the posted context to review.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that `wait` is terminating with a non-zero exit status?  Consider, for example:

```bsh
false || { echo "At least ..."; EXIT_CODE=1; }
```

That will generate the message and set `EXIT_CODE` appropriately.

I initially thought this was what you were looking for:

```bsh
wait ${job} || ( echo "At least ..."; EXIT_CODE=1 )
```

The problem with this approach is that the content of `(...)` is executed in a subshell – the change to the value of `EXIT_CODE` will be local to that subshell (i.e., it won't be visible when you try to read it later).

Consider, for example:

```bsh
EXIT_CODE=0
false || ( echo "At least ..." ; EXIT_CODE=1; echo "code: ${EXIT_CODE}" )
echo "final code: ${EXIT_CODE}"
```

The output will be:

```
At least ...
code: 1
final code: 0
```

I'd suggest not trying to be too fancy:

```bsh
if ! wait ${job}; then
    echo "At least ..."
    EXIT_CODE=1;
fi
```

Comment: Ok thanks, why the () instead of the {} though?

Comment: should it be if [[ ! wait ${job} ]] ; then